# Replace all but last instance of a character

Tags: regex, powershell

I am writing a quick PowerShell script to replace all periods except the last instance.
EG:

`hello. this. is a file.name.doc` → `hello this is a filename.doc`

So far from another post I was able to get this regexp, but it does not work with PowerShell:

```
\.(?=[^.]*\.)
```

As per https://www.regex101.com/, it only matches the first occurrence of a period.

EDIT:
Basically I need to apply this match and replace to a directory with sub directories. So far I have this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.*" | ForEach {
    $_.BaseName.Replace('.','') + $_.Extension
}
```

But it does not actually replace the items, and I do not think it is recursive.

I tried a few variations:

```
Get-Item -Filter "*.*" -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.Replace(".","")}
```

but I get the error message

> source and destination path must be different

Comment: Please note that PowerShell uses the 'g' and 'm' modifiers by default. Please add those into the modifier box on RegEx101.com ([example](https://www.regex101.com/r/wZ4vX7/1))

Comment: Wow.. that fixed it.. so if I was to match and replace, would the /gm be in the quotes with the regexp? as in `-match '/\.(?=[^.]*\.) /gm'` ?

Comment: On a side note, if this is really for file names, and you are working with a [FileInfo] object use the BaseName property not the Name property and it will automatically exclude the extension. So `Get-Item C:\Temp\File.Name.txt |ForEach{$_.BaseName.Replace('.','')+$_.Extension}` would output `FileName.txt`

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything in PowerShell. The g and m modifiers are implied without having to do any switches. If you want to explicitly state that you want to use those you include it in the RegEx pattern like: `-match '(?gm)/\.(?=[^.]*\.)'`

Comment: So when I actually use this to replace a name: `Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.Replace(".","") }`, I get an error that the source and destination shoul dbe different

Comment: Hm, `GCI ".\*" -Recurse |?{$_.BaseName -match '\.'}|Ren -NewName {$_.BaseName.Replace('.','') + $_.Extension}` That should do what you want it to. I'm guessing you are trying to rename a file without a period in it so the new name and old name are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate all the help

Answer (score 1):

I had the PowerShell side of things working but was stuck on the RegEx part. I was able to match either all the `"."` or only the last `"."` which was part of the file extension. Then I found this post with the missing link:    `\.(?=[^.]*\.)`

I added that to the rest of the PowerShell command and it worked perfectly.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\.(?=[^.]*\.)',' ' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exclude files that don't have a period in their basename from being renamed:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -like '*.*' } |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.Replace('.', '') + $_.Extension}
```